# NullReferenceException while handling FileSystemWatcher[]

Tags: c#, events, nullreferenceexception, filesystemwatcher

```
string[] directories = textBox5.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
FileSystemWatcher[] fileSysWatchers = new FileSystemWatcher[directories.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
        {
            directories[i] = directories[i].Replace("\n", "");
            directories[i] = directories[i].Replace("\r", "");
            fileSysWatchers[i].Path = directories[i];
            if (checkBox8.Checked)
            {
                fileSysWatchers[i].Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(Form1_Created);
            }
        }
```

I'm getting **NullReferenceException** in the next line:

```
fileSysWatchers[i].Path = directories[i];
```

I've checked **directories[0]** and found that it has no **.Path** but I don't understand why, it has to.
Basically, I want to create a specific FileSystemWatcher for each directory in some list and handle all their **"Created"** events using only one EventHandler. If there is some way to watch over multiple directories using only one FileSystemWatcher, I want to know that.
Sorry for my English if it's not perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only allocated an array capable of holding FileSystemWatcher instance but not the instances themselves.

You are missing the following line (before the one that crashes):

```
fileSysWatchers[i] = new FileSystemWatcher();
```

It's not `Path` that is `null`, it's the FileSystemWatcher instance itself.